# What is the right classes (DAO, DTO, ...) for custom queries?

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, dao, dto

**Hi!**

If I have to get a data from my database, like:

```
SELECT log_id, logtype
FROM
 log
 logtype
WHERE
 log.logtypeid = logtype.logtypeid
```

Tables:

**Log Table**

```
log_id (PK)
log_type_id (FK)
...
```

**Log Type Table**

```
log_type_id (PK)
description (VARCHAR)
```

Questions:

1 - In which class should I execute it? Should I add a method to my impl.LogDAO?

2 - The return from the method would be a DTO or BO?

**PS: I'm not using Hibernate or any other ORM, I'm trying to generate my own code**

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to generate your own code? Libraries exist for a reason.

Comment: I'd say you put it in the right place. The queries to database are put and executed in the DAO classes. The results are then put in DTO objects, to be used by the view for example. BO (you mean Business objects, right?), are classes where you put businness logic. I think EJBs have been built for that. In DTO, generally, you don't have Businness logic, but some fields to store results retrieved from the databse in a DAO class. Good answer for the academic reason though!!

Comment: Business Object - Thats right Patrick B.